# Decomposition of log into sum of square integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to have the following decomposition :
$$\ln|x-y|=\sum_kf_k(x)g_k(y)\text{ a.e. on }[0,1]\times[0,1] $$ where $f_k,g_k\in L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: Are you allowing sums of infinitely many terms? And if so, does "$=$" mean $L^2$ convergence of the sum, rather than pointwise convergence? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

$f(t) = \ln |t| \in L^2([-1,1])$, so the Fourier series
$\ln |t| = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j \exp(\pi i j t)$ 
converges in $L^2[0,1]$.  Moreover, since $f$ is smooth away from $0$ the series converges pointwise to $f(t)$ except at $0$ and possibly $\pm 1$.
Then for $x,y \in [0,1]$, $y - x \in [-1,1]$ so $$\ln |y-x| = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j \exp(\pi i j (y-x)) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j \exp(-\pi i j x) \exp(\pi i j y)$$
converges to $\ln |y-x|$ except at $y=x$ and perhaps at $(x=0,y=1)$ or $(x=1,y=0)$.